# SharePoint 2016 - Add-SPProfileSyncConnection with ADFS

Tags: powershell, user-profile-service, adfs, 2016

I want to use the following PowerShell command with ADFS.
How can I define to use the right Authentication Provider Instance?

[image]

My working command, but not working for ADFS:

```
 Add-SPProfileSyncConnection -ProfileServiceApplication $UPA -ConnectionForestName $Domain.DNSRoot -ConnectionDomain $Domain.DNSRoot -ConnectionUserName $User -ConnectionPassword $PWord -ConnectionSynchronizationOU $Domain.UsersContainer
```

How can I add my ADFS connection with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#provision connection with Claim Provider 
$UpaName = "ID-User-Profile-Service-Application"
$ForestName = "xy.com"
$DomainName = "xy"
$AdImportUserName = "User without domain\"
$AdImportPassword = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$SyncOU = "OU=my,DC=xy,DC=com"


Add-SPProfileSyncConnection -ProfileServiceApplication $UpaName -ConnectionClaimProviderIdValue "Name of your ADFS Connection" -ConnectionClaimProviderTypeValue "Trusted" -ConnectionForestName $ForestName -ConnectionDomain $DomainName -ConnectionUserName $AdImportUserName -ConnectionPassword $AdImportPassword -ConnectionSynchronizationOU $SyncOU
```